# Oracle - Calculate Previous balance using Current Balance

Tags: oracle, window-functions, calculated-columns

I have 2 tables.

1. Table TRAN has Account_no, Transaction_date and Transaction_Amount
2. Table BAL has Account_no and Current_balance

I want to populate results from table TRAN for an account number along with a running balance using the current_balance from BAL table. (the last row should have the current_balance and the previous row should have the previous balance that is current_balance minus the transaction amount)

Here is how the data looks like in both the tables:

[Table TRAN (1) and BAL (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95oz9.png)

Here is how i want the output to look like:

[The Output I Desire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2526.png)

Here is the code i tried using:

```
SELECT 
A.ACCOUNT_NO, 
A.TRANSACTION_DATE, 
A.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, 
B.CURRENT_BALANCE - LAG(A.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT) OVER (ORDER BY A.TRANSACTION_DATE) RUNNING_BALANCE 
FROM TRAN A 
INNER JOIN BAL B ON A.ACCOUNT_NO=B.ACCOUNT_NO
WHERE A.ACCOUNT_NO='11111111';
```

I get the below output:

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq1U1.png)

What changes do I make to the query to obtain "the output I desire"?

Comment: With the information given, do you think anyone can help you???  Please learn how to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "tried lag, lead and sum window functions"  Where???  We don't see any code in this posting.

Comment: Please edit the question and add some sample data and desired output for it along with your current code

Comment: I have edited the question and added the details, kindly review and help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After many attempts I finally figured out how to populate the previous balance by subtracting the transaction_amount from the current_balance.

```
SELECT 
A.ACCOUNT_NO, 
A.TRANSACTION_DATE, 
A.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, 
B.CURRENT_BALANCE - (SUM(A.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY A.ACCOUNT_NO ORDER BY A.TRANSACTION_DATE DESC)) +  A.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT RUNNING_BALANCE
FROM TRAN A 
INNER JOIN BAL B ON A.ACCOUNT_NO=B.ACCOUNT_NO
WHERE A.ACCOUNT_NO='11111111'
ORDER BY A.ACCOUNT_NO, A.TRANSACTION_DATE;
```

Please upvote this answer if you find it helpful.

The query displays the history from Table A, joins Table B and calculates the running_balance using the current_balance.

The SUM function is used to calculate the previous balance by subtracting the transaction_amount from the current_balance.

The OVER clause is used to specify the partitioning and ordering of the rows for the calculation of the running_balance.

The ORDER BY clause is used to order the rows in descending order by transaction_date so that the latest transaction has the current_balance.

The + A.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT part of the query adds back in the transaction_amount to get the previous balance.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you keeping two tables when you can keep a running balance from one table?

I did something similar. You may want to look at my solution.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
CUSTOMER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,IS_ACTIVE) AS 
SELECT 'E379466', 'Bonnie', 'Winterbottom','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Z098555', 'Peter', 'Clemenza','Y' FROM DUAL;


CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS (
ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
CUSTOMER_ID, VENDOR_ID,
IS_ACTIVE) AS 
SELECT 'THVQD6M9LR7AVK', 'E379466', 1, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT '0Z76WT5NTLRZPTW',
'Z098555', 1, 'Y' FROM DUAL;

create table transactions (
     transaction_id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    account_number VARCHAR2(15),
    transaction_type varchar2(1) DEFAULT 'C',
    transaction_amount NUMBER(10,2),
     transaction_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE 
);

insert  into transactions(
account_number, transaction_type, transaction_amount, transaction_date)
SELECT '0Z76WT5NTLRZPTW', 'D', (LEVEL * 100.57), date '2023-04-02' + level * interval '1 4' day to hour from dual
          connect by level <= 5
union all
SELECT '0Z76WT5NTLRZPTW', 'C', (LEVEL * 25.26), date '2023-04-04' + level * interval '1 4' day to hour from dual
          connect by level <= 5
union all
SELECT 'THVQD6M9LR7AVK', 'D', (LEVEL * 50.10), date '2023-05-10' + level * interval '1 7' day to hour from dual
          connect by level <= 13
union all
SELECT 'THVQD6M9LR7AVK', 'D', (LEVEL * 33.11), date '2023-05-10' + level * interval '1 7' day to hour from dual
          connect by level <= 9;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION   get_customer_balance
(  i_customer_id   IN   customers.customer_id%TYPE
)
RETURN  transactions.transaction_amount%TYPE
IS
  v_balance   transactions.transaction_amount%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM (
                 CASE  t.transaction_type
             WHEN  'C'
             THEN  -t.transaction_amount
             ELSE  t.transaction_amount
         END 
             )
  INTO   v_balance
  FROM   customer_accounts  ca
  JOIN   transactions       t  ON  t.account_number  = ca.account_number
  WHERE  ca.customer_id  = i_customer_id  -- one customer
  OR     ca.customer_id  IS NULL;         -- all customers

  RETURN v_balance;
END  get_customer_balance;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_account_balance(
  i_account_number IN TRANSACTIONS.ACCOUNT_NUMBER%TYPE
) RETURN TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT%TYPE
IS
  v_balance TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(
           CASE transaction_type WHEN 'C' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END 
           * transaction_amount
         )
  INTO   v_balance
  FROM   transactions
  WHERE  account_number = i_account_number -- one account
  OR     i_account_number IS NULL;         -- all accounts
  RETURN v_balance;
END;
/


SELECT CA.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
       C.FIRST_NAME,
       C.LAST_NAME, 
       CA.IS_ACTIVE,
       get_account_balance(ca.account_number) AS balance
FROM   CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS CA
       INNER JOIN customers c
       ON ca.customer_id = c.customer_id;

/* transaction history for an account */

WITH  daily_summary  AS
(
    SELECT  
account_number,
 transaction_date
    ,    SUM (DECODE (transaction_type, 'C', transaction_amount, 0))    AS credit_total
    ,    SUM (DECODE (transaction_type, 'D', transaction_amount , 0))   AS debit_total
    FROM     transactions
    GROUP BY  account_number, transaction_date 
)
SELECT   d.*
,    SUM (debit_total - credit_total)
       OVER (ORDER BY transaction_date) AS balance_to_date
FROM    daily_summary d
WHERE account_number = 
'0Z76WT5NTLRZPTW'
ORDER BY transaction_date;
```

Comment: :) I am not keeping two tables... for some reason, the company I work for has this information stored in different tables. I only have select access to these tables and to top it the histories are incomplete. LOL. Hence the request to use the current balance and subtract the transaction amount to populate the previous balance.. Let me know if you find anything. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't post images as people are very rarely want to enter your data. If asked a question provide DML/DDL with a small subset of data and expected results for that data. Look how I did it as a template.To be honest and no disrespect I believe your design is lousy and I'm not going to spend any time on your issue. Feel free to try and retro fit what I posted into your implementation.